# Background image inline style isn't being evaluated in DOM when set from "onbeforeunload" event in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

When setting the background-image from an "onbeforeunload" event handler in IE11 the DOM is updated with the correct background-image attribute but the new image isn't reflected in the window/frame.

Works as expected in other browsers including other versions of IE.

Is there something I am doing wrong or don't know about IE and onbeforeunload?

Using JSFIDDLE because it doesn't work in a Stack Overflow code snippet.

http://jsfiddle.net/carsont/jk8d3zmf/

NOTE: Hit "Run" to trigger the onbeforeunload event.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var $bg = $('#bg');

    $bg.css("background-image", 'url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAGUlEQVQIW2NkwAIYCQn+Z2BgACsiqBJuEgA0oAEG+FuXFQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")');

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        $bg.css("background-image", 'url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAATklEQVQYV2O0O3X+PwMDA8MhM0NGEI0LMBKtEJsJD27YgW1R0DgEtwWrdUQrxGYLY8V5iDUdhghrKFOITfenmXFgW/jSF+H3DNEKsdkCAO99IAvSBrFVAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")');

        return "Don't leave";
    };
});
```

```css
#bg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by forcing the DOM to update after setting the background image. Their are numerous ways to achieve this but I borrowed some from this thread: [jQuery CSS rendering - works in Firefox, not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927478/jquery-css-rendering-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome/8928389#8928389)